# Subtract totals from two different tables SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sum, left-join

I have two different tables, each with an amount related field with a code project (each project code has different amounts)

I want to add the amounts of each project code for each of the two tables and then get the difference (subtraction)

If I do:

```
SELECT codigo,
       ROUND(SUM(importe),2) AS 'resultado' 
FROM tabla1 
GROUP BY codigo

SELECT codigo,
       ROUND(SUM(importe),2) AS 'resultado' 
  FROM tabla2 
GROUP BY codigo
```

The SUM() function works correcty, but when I do the subtraction, the result is not correct:

```
SELECT t.codigo,
       ROUND(SUM(t.importe),2) - ROUND(SUM(d.importe),2) AS 'resultado' 
FROM tabla1 t
LEFT JOIN tabla2 d ON t.codigo=d.codigo 
GROUP BY t.codigo;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way:

```
SELECT codigo,
       sum(resultado1 - resultado2) AS 'resultado'
FROM  (       
SELECT codigo,
       ROUND(SUM(importe),2) AS 'resultado1',
       0 AS 'resultado2'
FROM tabla1 
GROUP BY codigo
UNION ALL
SELECT codigo,
       0 AS 'resultado1',
       ROUND(SUM(importe),2) AS 'resultado2'
  FROM tabla2 
GROUP BY codigo
) tablatot
GROUP BY codigo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.codigo,
       ROUND(SUM(ISNULL(t.importe, 0) - ISNULL(D.importe, 0)),2) AS 'resultado' 
FROM tabla1 t
LEFT JOIN tabla2 d ON t.codigo=d.codigo 
GROUP BY t.codigo;
```